# What is the C++ equivalent of a java.util.function.Consumer?

Tags: java, c++

For example, I have the following Java code:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Consumer<String> c = (x) -> System.out.println(x.toLowerCase());
    c.accept("Java2s.com");
  }
}
```

What will be the C++ equivalent?

Comment: Does this seem like such a complicated thing to you that you need an equivalent?

Comment: maybe? `std::function<void(const std::string&)> c = [](auto s){/*...*/};`

Comment: @Galik: Perfect, but I guess you could also use 'auto' in both places: auto c = [](auto x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; };

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I think so but then you'd have to specify `std::string` as your calling parameter if that's what your lambda expects, otherwise it may get a `const char*`.

Comment: @Galik: No, this is a new generic lambda. It will accept both `std::string` as well as `const char*`, and also any other printable type.

Comment: @MSalters Which is fine if the code you put inside the lambda doesn't expect one or the other.

Comment: @Galik: If the code inside expects a `std::string`, passing a `const char*` is fine. That's an implicit conversion. And no code should expect a `const char*`

Comment: @MSalters I suspect you might run into problems though, trying to call `x.size()` on a `const char*`. That's all I was trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really miss `accept`. You could also implement that:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class Food>
class Consumer {
 private:
  std::function<void(Food)> consume_;

 public:
  template <class Eater>
  Consumer<Food>(Eater consume) : consume_(consume){};

  void accept(Food food) { consume_(food); }
};

// Usage
int main() {
  Consumer<const std::string&> consumer([](
      const std::string& out) { std::cout << out << '\n'; });
  consumer.accept("My lovley string.");
  consumer.accept("Will be eaten!");
}
```

Or you could even:

```
template <class Food>
class Consumer {
 public:
  std::function<void(Food)> accept;

  template <class Eater>
  Consumer<Food>(Eater consume) : accept(consume){};
};
```

if you want to be able to swap out `accept` on the fly.

In other words I don't understand why a consumer exists in Java.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::function<void(const std::string&)>`.

You can initialize instances of this from function pointers, or from lambdas, e.g.:

```
void foo(const std::string &s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

// later
std::function<void(const std::string &)> c = foo;
c("Java2s.com");
```

or

```
std::function<void(const std::string &)> c = [](const std::string &) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
};
c("Java2s.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looking at a more complete example of how a `Consumer` is used in Java. For example, to print out the nodes in a tree, we might have something like this [code from CodeReview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63115/489):

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public static void preOrderTraversal(TreeViewItem treeNode,               
                                     Consumer<TreeViewItem> action) {
    action.accept(treeNode);
    for (TreeViewItem child : treeNode.getItems()) {
        preOrderTraversal(child, action);
    }
}

// Call that code with
preOrderTraversal(rootNode, (TreeViewItem node) -> System.out.println(node.getText()));
```

In C++, a few people use `std::function` to do this, but at least in my opinion that's usually a mistake. Instead, one should normally take advantage of the fact that C++'s template facility is much more general than Java generics, so we can use a template parameter for the `Consumer`.

Along with that, we'd typically make use of the fact that C++ supports operator overloading, so when we want to pass something that acts like a function, we can (and do) usually use function call syntax to invoke that function-like thing (might be a pointer to a function, or the closure from a lambda, etc.):

```
template <class Item, class Consumer>
void preOrderTraverse(Item i, Consumer action) { 
    action(item);
    for (auto & child : item->getChildren())
        preOrderTraverse(child, action);
}
```

Much like with the Java code, we can define the action with a lambda expression:

```
preOrderTraverse(rootNode, [](auto node) { std::cout << node->getText(); });
```

As a simple rule of thumb, assume that any use of `std::function` for a parameter type (at least to a non-virtual function<sup>1</sup>) in C++ is a mistake. For such a case, the type should be passed as a template parameter instead. An `std::function` would normally be reserved for a case where (for example) we need to accept some function-like object, store it, and invoke it later. The parameter type should still be a template parameter, but the object where we store it can reasonably be an `std::function`.

---

<sup>1. Since a virtual function can't be a template, if you need to pass a generic function like this to a function that has to be virtual, nearly your only real choice is to use `std::function` (or produce something similar on your own, which is unlikely to be a real improvement).</sup>

Comment: The chief exception would be for `std::function` as an argument to `virtual` functions, because those can't be templates.

Comment: @MSalters: Hmm...yeah, I suppose I should mention that.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that the functionality you need is based on the features **lambda expression** offers.

C++11 offers support for the lambda expression, and the following code, on a more generic level, offers what the code posted by you does.

```
auto algorithm = [&]( double x, double m, double b ) -> double
   {
   return m*x+b;
   };

int a=algorithm(1,2,3), b=algorithm(4,5,6);
```